# Passing parameters to shortcut mapping

Tags: informatica

We are attempting to update a logging table at the beginning and end of multiple workflows that exist in different Informatica repository folders.  In an attempt to reuse code, we created a generic mapping that calls a stored procedure to update the log table with parameters for the environment.  We then created shortcuts to that mapping in all of the different folders.

We were surprised to see that Informatica treats the session based off of the shared mapping as a reusable session and therefore isn't allowing us to pass in parameters.

Is there a way to pass parameters to a reusable session?
If not, is there another way to reuse a mapping in multiple folders with passing in a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, user error.  When creating the sessions in the workflows, I must have mistakenly selected "make reusable".  When I recreated the sessions, I didn't select that checkbox and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you've got this one resolved. I'll just add a note to clarify:

It's not possible to perform any pre- or post-session variable assignment on a reusable session. It has its reasons - this is a part of session definition, and can't be modified in one workflow, as it would affect other instances. At the moment this feature is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You pass parameters to a reusable session same as for normal session i.e. you set the parameter file name for the session and make sure it contains the variable setting statements.

You can even override the default parameter file at each session task instance if you prefer.

It sounds more like your syntax within your parameter file is what is preventing the values from being picked i.e. each section of the parameter file usually is fully qualified with a header in square brackets where you specify which workflow the settings are for. In this way, the same parameter file can apply different overrides depending on what is calling it. You can see some examples here https://network.informatica.com/thread/14568